# unable to install packages- raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

I have been trying to get this working for a lot of hours now but no success.
Here is what I have done-

1. ping 8.8.8.8 works
2. Also added `nameserver 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4` in etc/resolv.conf as suggested on many forums (I have some of my company's nameservers added along as well)
3. I have also updated my source.list according to mentioned here- https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository. <strike>I have tried changing it to deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi but hasn't helped.</strike>
4. tried sudo apt-get update, upgrade
5. Also added my company's proxy servers using `export http_proxy`

I am trying to install pip- `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` (any package basically)

Error it is giving

```
E: Unable to locate package
```

It was earlier giving `connection closed, failed to fetch errors` but now is giving above. Please suggest what should be done.

**Update**
I have tried to ping `google.com` but it doesn't work.

I have changed */etc/apt/sources.list* to **stretch** now so my sources.list is

```
deb mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

and */etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list* is

```
archive.raspberry.org/raspbian stretch main contrib non-free
```

Still getting the same error- unable to locate package.

Comment: wheezy? Why did you put that in the list file? We left that behind 5 years or so ago... Put sources.list and raspi.list back in its original state, then run sudo apt update and add the output to your question

Comment: I have changed it to stretch now- so my sources.list is- deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi and raspi.list is-  http://archive.raspberry.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free. Still getting the same error- unable to locate package

Comment: sudo apt-update ends with 3 errors as well- 2 failed to fetch errors and the other- some index files failed to download.

Comment: You say `ping 8.8.8.8` works. Does `ping google.com` also work?

Comment: @Ingo, you are right. ping google.com doesn't work but ping 8.8.8.8 works. Seems it is not able to resolve DNS. What should be done?

Comment: @jsotola, I only have terminal- did not set up the UI

Comment: i only asked because i did not know if you knew about DNS. ..... deleting my comments .... less clutter

Comment: note: you can install a text based web browser like `lynx` or `elinks` .... you may already have it installed

Answer (score 1):

First of all: never touch `/etc/resolv.conf`. It does not help because this file is managed by *openresolv* and entries will be overwritten. Instead setup the dns server in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. There are some examples with `static domain_name_servers=` in it.

`ping 8.8.8.8` works so we are certain that the internet connection is available. But `ping google.com` does not work so it is very likely that your domain name resolution does not work. You can check with `dig` where the problem is. How to do that look at [No Internet, can ping to IPs but not hostnames](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88049/79866).

You can try to set

```
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
```

in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. Then restart **dhcpcd**:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd.service
```

and check if this works:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
```

Comment: is there a service you need to restart to make these changes take effect?

Comment: @AshtonWiersdorf Yes, after modifying `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` you have to restart dhcpcd. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out before you posted; I've run `sudo service dhcpcd restart`, and it *seems* to work. Is there a difference?

Comment: @AshtonWiersdorf Yes, there is a difference. Using old style SysV commands like `service xxx restart` is deprecated and only emulated by systemd. You should use the commands from systemd. It is the leading system.